# пересчет цены в зависимости от изменяемого кол-ва без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Увы не разбираюсь в написании скриптов и примеры из гугла не смог подогнать под свои нужды, поэтому прошу совета у знающих.

Есть вот такая конструкция:

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><?echo $service_element?></a>
        </td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> <?echo $service_price?> <i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
        <td>
            <div class="b-count">
                <button class="b-count__button b-count__button_minus" id="minus"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i></button>
                <input type="text" class="b-count__input" id="qty"  value="<? echo $qty ?>"></input>
                <button class="b-count__button b-count__button_plus" id="plus"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Тут сумма <i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
    </tr>
```

Есть переменная, которая содержит цену - $service_price. Есть input в котором нужно подставить кол-во, либо вручную с клавиатуры либо при помощи кнопок "+" и "-". Кнопки увеличивают или уменьшают значение input на 1. Сумма, которая выводится ниже, должна быть динамичной и меняться в зависимости от данных в input.

Не могли бы знающие помочь с написанием скрипта для расчета суммы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Событием onClick на баттонах производим вычисление через функции.
Обратите внимание на свойство type инпута количества - он должен быть числовым, мало ли что юзер туда введёт.
Сам инпут проверяется при изменении на разрешённый диапазон количества, иначе можете продать и -100 и 10^10. Так же функцией просчитываем сумму и подставляем.

```
<span id="price_here">100</span>

<button onclick="qminus('#qty');" class="b-count__button b-count__button_minus" id="minus">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>
</button>
<input type="number" onchange="check_qty($(this),1,100);" name="qty" class="b-count__input" id="qty"  value="<? echo $qty ?>" />
<button onclick="qplus('#qty');" class="b-count__button b-count__button_plus" id="plus">
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
</button>

<span id="sum_here"></span>
```

Код jQuery:

```
<script>
    function qminus(el,min){
        var e = $(el);
        var compare = parseInt(e.val());
        var i = ((compare - 1) < min) ? min : compare - 1;
        e.val(i);
        show_price($('#sum_here'),$('#price_here'),i);
    }
    function qplus(el,max){
        var e = $(el);
        var compare = parseInt(e.val());
        var i = ((compare + 1) > max) ? max : compare + 1;
        e.val(i);
        show_price($('#sum_here'),$('#price_here'),i);
    }
    function check_qty(el,min,max){
        var compare = parseInt(el.val());
        if(compare < min){
            el.val(min);
            alert(min + ' is minimal qty');
        }
        if(compare > max){
            el.val(max);
            alert(max + ' is maximum qty');
        }
        show_price($('#sum_here'),$('#price_here'),el.val());
    }
    function show_price(el,pr,ch){
        var sum = pr.html() * ch;
        el.html(sum);
    }
</script>
```

Это один из множества вариантов разрешения такой задачи.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, решил воспользоватся вашим вариантом. Все подключил, но при нажатии на кнопку пишет 
'show_price is not defined'. Остальной код jquery работает на сайте

Comment: Поправил код. Забыл описать функцию show_price(). Точнее не там разместил

Comment: Обнаружил еще небольшую ошибку вот тут:
'function check_qty(el,min,max){
show_price($('#sum_here'),$('#price_here'),i);
}'

Лишняя буква i. 

В целом все работает. Спасибо)

Comment: Это очепятка. Третий аргумент принимает текущее кол-во, и там должно быть el.val(). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если с аяксом, то вот так

```
jQuery("#plus").click(function(event) {
   quntity=jQuery("#qty").val()+1; //увеличиваем на 1
   aj("handler.php", false, "html", {"quntity":quntity}, s_handler); //запрос. обратите внимание на false и true (синхронно\асинхронно)
});

function s_handler(result) {
    jQuery("#summ").html(result); //вставляем результат в div c ид summ
}

function aj(url, async, datatype, data, success) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        async: async,
        //timeout: 20000, //Время ожидания выполнения запроса 20с.
        dataType: datatype,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        error: function(err){console.log(err);}
    });
}
```

И нужно как-то обозначить место, куда вставляем сумма. Например

```
<td><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><div id='summ'>Тут сумма</div><i class="fa fa-rub"></i></td>
```

Но в этом случае обработчику handler.php нужно ещё отсылать и уникальный ИД товара, чтобы там всё чётко прошло (который храним где-нибудь в скрытом поле в html). Но потом (когда будет подтверждать заказа и т.п.) нужно будет опять всё проверять. Потому предлагаю другой вариант:

В скрытом поле в вашем html хранить стоимость товара за 1 единицу. И просто js считать исходя из этой стоимости. При подтверждении и т.п. уже потом всё проверяем на стороне php, используя код товара, выбирая из БД стоимость одной единицы, перемножая - чтобы защититься от подделывания стоимости. Ведь не составит труда изменить код html страницы. Короче:

```
jQuery("#plus").click(function(event) {
    price=jQuery("#price").val(); //берём цену за 1 единицу из input type=hidden
    quntity=jQuery("#qty").val()+1; //увеличиваем на 1
    total=price*quntity; //итоговая стоимость
    jQuery("#summ").html(total); //выводим на страницу в div
});
```

Answer (score 1):

И тут Остапа понесло...

```js
let log   = document.querySelector('#log');

// Навешиваем обработчики на кнопки и поля ввода
// Правильнее было бы запились блэкджек и делегирование
// Но лень :)
Array.from(document.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('.ch_btn')).forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', btnHandler);
  e.parentNode.querySelector('.numOfProduct').addEventListener('keydown', inpHandler);
});

// Обрабатываем нажатие на кнопку
function btnHandler(e){
  // Нашли поле для этой кнопки (привязано к разметке, что нехорошо)
  let inp = this.parentNode.querySelector('.numOfProduct'),
      val = +inp.value || 0,
      // Если кнопка плюса, увеличиваем значение, иначе уменьшаем (логика!)
      newValue = this.classList.contains('plus_sign') ? val + 1 : val - 1;
  
  // Минусовые значение не обрабатываем
  if(newValue < 0)
    e.preventDefault();
  else
  // После проверки либо ставим новое значение, либо вызываем обработчик ошибки
  // Когда async/await хорошо поддерживать будут, можно будет делать так:
  //
  // if(await checkAvailability(inp.dataset.id, newValue))
  //   inp.value = newValue;
  // else
  //   notFound(inp, newValue);
    checkAvailability(inp.dataset.id, newValue)
        .then(_ => inp.value = newValue)
        .catch(_ => notFound(inp, newValue));
}

function inpHandler(e){
  let keyCode = e.keyCode,
      val     = +this.value;

  // Если вводят не число - лесом их!
  if(e.key.length === 1 && /\D+/.test(e.key))
    e.preventDefault();
  
  // Тут бы ещё проверку на введённое число сделать, но это домашнее задание
  
  // Если это стрелки вверх (38) и вниз (40)
  if(keyCode === 38 || keyCode === 40){
    // Вычисляем значение
    let newValue = keyCode === 38 ? val + 1 : val - 1;
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Меньше нуля тоже лесом
    if(newValue < 0)
      return;
    
    // Аналогично: проверили, если можно, ставим, иначе ошибка
    checkAvailability(this.dataset.id, newValue)
      .then(_ => this.value = newValue)
      .catch(_ => notFound(this, newValue));
  }
}

// Простейший уведомитель :)
const notFound = (inp, num) => {
  let humanName = inp.closest('tr').children[0].innerHTML,
      div       = document.createElement('DIV');
  
  div.innerHTML = `Товара "<strong>${humanName}</strong>" в таком количестве (<strong>${num}</strong>) не найдено!`;
  log.appendChild(div);
  
  setTimeout(_ => div.remove(), 1000);
};


// Типа БД
let bd = {
  "pinkHandcuffs"  : 10,
  "roomOfTheTower" : 5,
  "h2o"            : 1
},
checkAvailability = (type, num) => 
  // Эмулируем асинхронность
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!(type in bd))
      return false;
  
    // Если требуемое число есть в БД, разрешаем позитивно, иначе негативно
    setTimeout(_ => {
      if(bd[type] >= num)
        resolve();
      else
        reject();
     }, 0);
  });
```

```css
input:focus{outline: none;}
#log{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Розовые наручники</td>
    <td>
      <input type='button' class='ch_btn plus_sign' value='+' />
      <input type='text' class='numOfProduct' data-id='pinkHandcuffs' size='2' value='0' />
      <input type='button' class='ch_btn minus_sign' value='-' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Личные казематы в Тауэре</td>
    <td>
      <input type='button' class='ch_btn plus_sign' value='+' />
      <input type='text' class='numOfProduct' data-id='roomOfTheTower' size='2' value='0' />
      <input type='button' class='ch_btn minus_sign' value='-' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Дигидрогена монооксид</td>
    <td>
      <input type='button' class='ch_btn plus_sign' value='+' />
      <input type='text' class='numOfProduct' data-id='h2o' size='2' value='0' />
      <input type='button' class='ch_btn minus_sign' value='-' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table><br />
<div id='log'></div>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ, обязательно разберу код когда закончу проект.

Comment: @Taarim, пожалуйста, постарался обильно откомментировать для более лёгкого понимания.